# how to access all textbox value which is in foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

am creating textbox according sku, means if i got multiple sku of product textbox willl created against sku. in this case i have 2 sku so using foreach loop twos rows will created of product information and text box have name.

```html
 <td>
   <input class="form-control cmbeditqty" type="text" id="cmbeditqty-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 100px;"  name="qty[<?php echo $parentsku; ?>][]" value="<?php echo  $comboarraydet['subquantity']; ?>">      
 </td>  
 <td>
     <input class="form-control cmbeditprice" type="text" id="cmbeditprice-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 100px;"  name="itemprice[<?php echo $parentsku; ?>][]" value="<?php echo  number_format($comboarraydet['subitemprice'], 2); ?>"> 
  </td>  
 <td>
     <input class="form-control cmbedittax" type="text" id="cmbedittax-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 100px;"  name="tax[<?php echo $parentsku; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $comboarraydet['subtax']; ?>"> 
   </td>  
   <td>
       <input class="form-control cmbeditship" type="text" id="cmbeditship-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 100px;"  name="shipping[<?php echo $parentsku; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $comboarraydet['subshipping']; ?>"> 
  </td>  
  <td style="width:19%;">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cmbeditCommission" style="width: 100px;"  name="cmbeditCommission[<?php echo $parentsku; ?>][]" value="<?php echo  number_format($comboarraydet['subcommision'],2); ?>">
</td>
   <td style="width:19%;">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cmbeditDiscount" style="width: 100px;"  name="cmbeditDiscount[<?php echo $parentsku; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $subdiscount; ?>">
   </td>
```

so if there is 2 rows of quantity, price ...etc. i want all value in  ajax for inserting in data base as multiple rows.

Comment: get the data using class name

Comment: i can't.. beacuse its show only ontime. i have 2 rows now, want to acees both rows value

Comment: Forms are submitted with key/value pairs. The key is the name attribute within the input control. You controls do not have name attribute set. To submit multiple values under the one key you append [] to the control name i.e. <input type='text' name='myText[]'>. php will pick these up as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Give a common class name to your textboxes which you wan to get values in the JS. lets take it as skuDetails

Then you can get the details using below code

```
$('.skuDetails').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);

    var value = currentElement.val(); // if it is an input/select/textarea field

});
```

If you have multiple dynamic data and you need to differentiate them then you have to give a dynamic id also to the textboxes.

Comment: this means for qantity 
$('.cmbeditqty').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);

    var value = currentElement.val(); // if it is an input/select/textarea field

});

for price 
$('.cmbeditprice').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);

    var value = currentElement.val(); // if it is an input/select/textarea field

});

but how can use both input value for insert or update?

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you need the values of your textboxes inside your JavaScript code right ?

Comment: ok then you can give a common class for all these textboxes, so you can access all these using the class name. Then the next step , differentiate the  inputs, for that you have to give dymaic ids to the inputs. You can get the id of input inside foreach loop and using the id you can differentiate

Comment: <input class="form-control cmbeditship" type="text" id="cmbeditship-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 100px;"  name="shipping[<?php echo $parentsku; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $comboarraydet['subshipping']; ?>"> 

here i have dynamic id appending $i ;
till i got it. "You can get the id of input inside foreach loop and using the id you can differentiate" please elaborate

Comment: I dont know what is the value of 'i' here. Anyway we can take example of id cmbeditprice cmbeditprice-<?php echo $i . So inside your look get the id of input like $(this).id ; oncs you get the id you will get to know its related to cmbeditprice .Because id starting with string  cmbeditprice. You can do a check over there to find whether it is related to cmbeditprice  or any other. oncs that check got over you will get to know that particular textbox is related to which functionality. Then based on that you can save it to database. If it is not a new entry and it is an updation then

Comment: you could maintain the primary key or any unique details related to that row in a hidden field or something then using that you can update the data in the db

Answer (score 0):

***Use array [] for name.rest will be taken care by your server logic.
I mean price field can be named as price[]***

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
  formdata = $("form").serialize()
  console.log(formdata)
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<form>
<div>
<input type="text" name='quantity[]' placeholder='quantity'>
<input type="text" name='price[]' placeholder='price'>
</div>

<div>
<input type="text" name='quantity[]' placeholder='quantity'>
<input type="text" name='price[]' placeholder='price'>
</div>


<input type="submit">
</form>
```